# Is there a more efficient way to fetch this array?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, sqlite

I have a model Item, which users can vote on by creating either a new UpVote or DownVote. When a UpVote or Downvote is created, it records the user's ip address and the Item's id. I want to list an array of the first 100 Items that have not been voted on by the current user's ip.

So far, here's what I have:

**schema**

```
create_table "up_votes", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "ip"
end

create_table "down_votes", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "ip"
end
```

**model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  def up_votes_array
    self.up_votes.map(&:ip).to_a
  end

  def down_votes_array
    self.down_votes.map(&:ip).to_a
  end

  def up_voted?(ip)
    self.up_votes_array.include? ip
  end

  def down_voted?(ip)
    self.down_votes_array.include? ip
  end
```

**controller**

```
@not_voted = Item.where(show: true).select { |item| !item.up_voted?(request.remote_ip) }.select { |thing| !item.down_voted?(request.remote_ip) }.sort_by(&:alphabetical).reverse.first(100).shuffle
```

---

It works, but there's something about all that that seems unnecessarily complicated, and I'm worried that as my database grows, it may become inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to get this array?

I'm using Rails 4 and Sqlite3.

Comment: what is `Thing` here. And what's it's association with Item?

Comment: Oops sorry, I mixed it up with another table I have. It's supposed to be `Item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ideal query for this will be something like this:

`Item.where(show: true).joins(:up_votes).joins(:down_votes).where('up_votes.ip != ?', request.remote_ip).where('down_votes.ip != ?', request.remote_ip).limit(100)`

This will produce an optimal query and load 100 rows in your memory, in contrast of the query given where it loads entire table for `Item` and all iterates all over it's upvotes and downvotes to check.

You can probably also club the query together as:
`Item.where(show: true).joins(:up_votes).joins(:down_votes).where('up_votes.ip != ? and down_votes.ip != ', request.remote_ip, request.remote_ip).limit(100)`

Comment: Is this going to work?  What if an item has an up_vote from both the session ip and some other ip?  It has at least one up_vote which is != ip so it'll be selected when it shouldn't be.

Comment: It wouldn't select that item if any of it's upvote or downvote has request.remote_ip, even if some other upvote or downvote of *that* item has some ip. It should return a query like : `select * from items inner join up_votes on items.id = up_votes.item_id inner join down_votes on items.id = down_votes.item_id where up_votes.ip <> "127.0.0.1" and down_votes.ip <> "127.0.0.1" limit 3`. Give it a shot.

Comment: Cool.  Always an education, hanging around here. :)